# What is the best statistical measurement for collocational analysis?

Tags: t-test, mutual-information, z-test, corpus-linguistics

I am a beginner with statistics and corpus linguistics, so sorry in advance if my explanation have gaps in it.

So I want to perform corpus linguistics collocational strength analysis on a given corpus, namely a corpus of presidential speech in a country. As a general rule of thumb, by using Mutual Information measurement, we typically measure the strength of a collocation by counting:

1. The frequency of x-y–word-pair in a given corpus (xyw);
2. The frequency of x-word in a given corpus (xw);
3. The frequency of y-word in a given corpus (xy);
4. The total frequency of words in a given corpus (w)

Using the following formula, in Excel: Log((xyw/w)/((xw/w)*(xy/w)),2)

One can actually use other measurement, such as T-test, Z-test, and Log Likelihood to measure the strength of a collocation in a corpus.

My question is, what is the most suitable measurement, and why is that?